# Last table column does not have rowspan operating as it should do

Tags: php

Got a simple question which I can't seem to figure out. If you open up the php fiddle, how come in the result section that the last column does not have its rowspan fill each row? I have included the rowspan like I have in the other columns which requires rowspan but it does not work for this column.

Does anybody know what is causing this?

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

Full table code:

```
<table id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='incorrectanswerth'>Incorrect Answer</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='totalmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans)
{
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    $row_count = 0;
    $inc_ans = array_values($inc_ans);

?>

<tr class="questiontd">

<td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionNo?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span?>"><?php echo$questionNo?>
<input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo$questionNo?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="q<?php echo$questionNo?>_ans_org" class="q<?php echo$questionNo?>_ans_org" value="<?php echo$searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="q<?php echo$questionNo?>_ans" class="q<?php echo$questionNo?>_ans" value="<?php echo$searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]?>">
    </td>

    <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span?>"><?php echo$searchQuestionContent[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]?> </td>

<td class="answertd"><?php echo$inc_ans[$row_count];?>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php echo$inc_ans[$row_count];?>">
</td>

<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionNo?>_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php echo$questionNo?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" />
</td>


<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span?>"><?php echo$totalMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]?></td>

<td class="noofmarkstd q<?php echo$questionNo?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?php$q_row_span?>"><?php echo"<strong>".$searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]."</strong>"?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
        //remaining incorrect answers in separate row (if any) follows here
    if($row_count < $q_row_span - 1) 
    {
        for($i=($row_count + 1); $i<$q_row_span; $i++) { ?>     
            <tr>
            <td class="answertd"><?php echo$inc_ans[$i];?>
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php echo$inc_ans[$i];?>">
            </td>

            <td class="answermarkstd">
            <input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionNo?>_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php echo$questionNo?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" />
            </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `echo` in the line below:

```
<td class="noofmarkstd q<?php echo $questionNo?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?php$q_row_span?>"><?php echo"<strong>".$searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]."</strong>"?></td>
```

line about 105-107

See the [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jd2-yi4)

By the way php must have notified you of the error.

Comment: I thought I put error report on but I ended up being a complete full and put the remove notice code instead. Im a fool